# Go is querying from the wrong database when using multiple databases with godotenv

Tags: postgresql, go, environment-variables

I'm trying to query from multiple databases. Each database is connected using the following function:

```golang
func connectDB(dbEnv str) *sql.DB{
    // Loading environment variables from local.env file
    
    err1 := godotenv.Load(dbEnv)
    if err1 != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Some error occured. Err: %s", err1)
    }
    dialect := os.Getenv("DIALECT")
    host := os.Getenv("HOST")
    dbPort := os.Getenv("DBPORT")
    user := os.Getenv("USER")
    dbName := os.Getenv("NAME")
    password := os.Getenv("PASSWORD")

    // Database connection string
    dbURI := fmt.Sprintf("port=%s host=%s user=%s "+"password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", dbPort, host, user, password, dbName)

    // Create database object
    db, err := sql.Open(dialect,dbURI)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return db

}

type order struct{
    OrderID string `json:"orderID"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type book struct{
    OrderID string `json:"orderID"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func getOrders(db *sql.DB) []order {

    var (
        orderID string
        name string
    )

    var allRows = []order{}
    query := `
        SELECT orderID, name
        FROM orders.orders;
`
    //Get rows using the query
    rows, err := db.Query(query)
    if err != nil { //Log if error
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    
    // Add each row into the "allRows" slice
    for rows.Next() {

        err := rows.Scan(&orderID, &name, &date)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        //Create new order struct with the received data
        row := order{
            OrderID: orderID,
            Name:  name,
        }
        allRows = append(allRows, row)
    }
    //Log if error
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return allRows
}

func getBooks(db *sql.DB) []book{
    var (
        bookID string
        name string
    )

    var allRows = []book{}
    query := `
        SELECT bookID, name
        FROM books.books;
        `
    //Get rows using the query
    rows, err := db.Query(query)
    if err != nil { //Log if error
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    
    // Add each row into the "allRows" slice
    for rows.Next() {

        err := rows.Scan(&bookID, &name)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        //Create new book struct with the received data
        row := book{
            BookID: bookID,
            Name:  name,
        }
        allRows = append(allRows, row)
    }
    //Log if error
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return allRows
}


func main() {

    ordersDB:= connectDB("ordersDB.env")
    booksDB:= connectDB("booksDB.env")

    orders := getOrders(ordersDB)
    books := getBooks(booksDB)
}
```

The issue is that when I use ordersDB first, the program only recognizes the table in ordersDB. And when I use booksDB first, the program only recognizes the table in booksDB.
When I try to query a table in booksDB after using ordersDB, it is giving me "relation "books.books" does not exist" error. When I try to query a table in ordersDB after using booksDB, it gives "relation "orders.orders" does not exist"
Is there a better way to connect to multiple databases?

Comment: Don't use godotenv (which is kinda non-Go-ish) or use it correctly.

Comment: @Volker what's the Go-ish way?

Comment: Read environment variables or command line arguments. Env-files are strange concept from JavaScript and PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `github.com/joho/godotenv` to load the database configuration from the environment. Summarising (and cutting out a lot of detail) what you are doing is:

```
godotenv.Load("ordersDB.env")
host := os.Getenv("HOST")
// Connect to DB
godotenv.Load("booksDB.env")
host := os.Getenv("HOST")
// Connect to DB 2
```

However as stated in [the docs](https://github.com/joho/godotenv#precedence--conventions) "Existing envs take precedence of envs that are loaded later". This is also stated more clearly [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/joho/godotenv#Load) "It's important to note that it WILL NOT OVERRIDE an env variable that already exists".

So your code will load in the first `.env` file, populate the environment variables, and connect to the database. You will then load the second `.env` file but, because the environmental variables are already set, they will not be changed and you will connect to the same database a second time.

As a work around you could use [Overload](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/joho/godotenv#Overload). However it's probably better to reconsider your use of environmental variables (and perhaps use different variables for the second connection).

Comment: Thanks so much, I've managed to fix the existing issue but what is the standard for setting up a second connection generally?

Comment: I don't think there is really a standard for this ([postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) uses `PGHOST` within `libpq`). Personally I use something descriptive i.e. `GREATAPP_DB=postgresql://user:pass@127.0.0.1:5432/db?sslmode=disable` - I find the URL easier because it contains everything needed in one string.